# Using a subroutine from another file

Tags: perl

Consider:

#### File `display.pl`

```
disp{
    my $p = shift;
    print $p;
}
```

#### File `temp.pl`

```
require "display.pl";

$item = "asd";

&disp($item);
```

When I executed `temp.pl`, it gave an error:

> can't find method "disp" without a package or a object reference at display.pl line 2.

Comment: You should use `disp($item)`, not `&disp($item)`, unless you specifically mean to circumvent prototypes. If you have no idea what that meant, just don't use `&`. See [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) for the full explanation.

Answer (score 11):

You forgot to write `sub` before `disp{` in `display.pl`, so Perl doesn't know that you are trying to define a function.

Always use `strict` and `warnings`, and you will avoid such problems.  Also, as noted by @NEW, you need to end `display.pl` with a `1;` because `require` requires that a file end with a true value.

Corrected, your code would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub disp {
    my $p = shift;
    print $p;
}

1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Avoid errors by using

```
use strict ;
use warnings;
```

**Note** that you need the 1; at the end of the file like

```
sub disp{ 
    my $p=shift;  
   print $p;
 } 
1;
```

This is because Perl needs the last expression in the file to return a true value.

If the require file (display.pl) is in another directory you will need to specify the absolute path:

You don't need to worry about recursive requiring (e.g. requiring a file that requires the current file), Perl will handle everything.

SEE ALSO

**perldoc -f require** and  **perldoc -q require** and  **perldoc perlmod** for better understanding.